# getting specific hyphen letter number mix using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
import re
s = 'N18-2181, 59-year-old, E12-34567, O18-517, BL-17-1111, 18S-8, L1-12, 21-year old, 40-year-old, 67-years, BL-14-111, 91-years, AL-1-2, 01-13-2019, 1-22-2001'
reg = r'[()\d-]{7,}'
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
```

I have the following `reg` that gives the following

```
['18-2181', '12-34567', '-17-1111', '-14-111', '01-13-2019', '1-22-2001']
```

But I would like the following output

```
['N18-2181', 'E12-34567', 'O18-517', 'BL-17-1111', '18S-8', 'L1-12', '6BL-14-111', 'AL-1-2']
```

How do I tweak `reg = r'[()\d-]{7,}'` to get the output I have above?

Comment: What makes `185-8` or `BL-17-1111` valid but not `01-13-2019`?

Comment: it's actually `18S-8`

Comment: so `01-13-2019` is not vaild because it does not contain a letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should give you the results you want. It asserts that the first group contains at least one alphabetic character, then captures a group of alphanumeric characters followed by 1 or 2 groups of `-` and digits.

```
\b(?=\d*[A-Z])((?:[A-Z0-9]+)(?:-\d+){1,2})\b
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IHX8Vv/3)

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/NTYS52808)